# Flex - change in Timezone only picked up on Minutes Change. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a timer running, that every second, checks the systems Date/Time, and updates 
the date displayed on the application.

If I change the system time, the app updates the next second. If I change the system timezone, the app only registers this change when the current minute changes.

I have a little sample app that shows the problem occuring (if you wish to see for yourself)

Where I call `localDate:Date = new Date()`, the `localDate.timezoneOffset` does not reflect the current system timzone until the current minute changes. But if I change the system seconds, they update on the next timer tick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            myTimer = new Timer(1000, 0);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler, false, 0, true);
            myTimer.start();
        }

        private function timerHandler( event:TimerEvent):void{
            var localTime:Date = new Date();
            offsetLabel.text = localTime.timezoneOffset.toString();
            secondsLabel.text = localTime.seconds.toString();
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Label id="offsetLabel" x="33" y="24" width="223" height="58" fontSize="15"/>
<mx:Label id="secondsLabel" x="33" y="90" width="223" height="58" fontSize="15"/>
```

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with `getTimezoneOffset()`?

Comment: Will check now in a second

Comment: Yeah, its the same thing. In debug mode, the new localTime object actually only updates the timezoneOffset value after the minute changes